# IllegalArgumentException Port out of range: -1 in retrofit interceptors

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am investigating an issue that has started occurring in our app which configures a pac file proxy on the device.
One thing I noticed is that before this started occurring, we increased retrofit version from 2.6.0 to 2.9.0 which uses OkHttp3.
I understand the general root cause and that's that the okhttp is trying to obey the system settings and it's trying to connect to the proxy specified by the device. But our proxy is configured using the pac file url, not a static host with a port.

Stacktrace of the issue:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
   at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:144)
   at java.net.InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(InetSocketAddress.java:269)
   at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector$1.run(DefaultProxySelector.java:315)
   at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector$1.run(DefaultProxySelector.java:219)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:43)
   at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:218)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector$resetNextProxy$1.invoke(RouteSelector.java:106)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextProxy(RouteSelector.java:113)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.<init>(RouteSelector.java:53)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:209)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:76)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.java:245)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:32)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:100)
   at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:96)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:100)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:83)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:100)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:76)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:100)
```

I am looking for some hint on what might be causing this issue.
It could be a bug in the library since all seems to be leading to the upgrade, but I am open to any suggestions. It does not seem to be related to any Android version, security patch, device model or anything of that kind.

Comment: If you fetch the pac file (it's javascript) does it look ok? What does `System.out.println(ProxySelector.getDefault().select(URI.create("your url")));` return?

Comment: This issue only occurs in Crashlytics and I am not able to reproduce it, so it must be some edge case causing terrible things.
I tried what you suggested anyway. When a request is proxied, the log says "HTTP @ localhost:34930" which is where the proxy service runs. The same is retrievable form the system properties " httpProxy: localhost httpPort:37985". If the proxy is not configured, the log says "DIRECT" and the system properties are: "httpProxy:  httpPort:0". This all comes form my devtesting where I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: This seems like it could even be a misconfiguted network config in some random workplace

Comment: wouldn't it be better if OkHttp did not throw exceptions in such cases but rather ignored proxy settings?

Comment: OkHttp will generally rely on well behaved implementations you the system interfaces.  You can wrap the ProxySelector API and pass that into OkHttp. It is probably only worth handling this in every HTTP framework out there if it's something like a probably in a built version of Android that can't be fixed.